# No legal conversion to 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, templates

Please take a look at this code and run it:
I'm getting very strange error:
Error   1   error C2663: 'Allocator::allocate_help' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

```
template<class FailureSignal>
class Allocator
{
private:
    template<class Exception,class Argument>
    void allocate_help(const Argument& arg,Int2Type<true>)
    {
    }

    template<class Exception,class Argument>
    std::nullptr_t allocate_help(const Argument& arg,Int2Type<false>)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

public:
    template<class T>
    void Allocate(signed long int nObjects,T** ptr = 0)const
    {
    allocate_help<std::bad_alloc>(1,Int2Type<true>());  
    }

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Allocator<int> all;
    all.Allocate<int>(1);
    return 0;
}
```

I absolutely do not understand this err msg. Hope someone can help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Cant compile as you requested.  `Int2Type` isnt declared/defined

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I noticed `Allocate` is declared `const` but `allocate_help` is not - could that be related to the issue?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Couldn't they provide bit more informative msg?

Comment: @There: search and [you shall find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhx1a546.aspx "Compiler Error C2663"). There are two suggested resolutions. *1: Remove the **const** from the object declaration. 2. Add **const** to one of the member function overloads.* (This is the first hit on Google when searching for C2663)

Comment: @There: It's very informative in its way :) It says it can't convert the `this` pointer (i.e. from `const Allocator<int>*` to `Allocator<int>*` in this case) for either of the `allocate_help` overloads.

Comment: Yes, a *very* informative and clear error message. Couldn't be any clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error which was also caused by `const` but in a bit different way.

I have two virtual functions (overloads), one was `const` and the other was not. This was causing the problem. Turns out if you want to overload a function, they both need to match if they are `const` or not.

```
virtual void value() const = 0;
virtual void value(MyStruct & struct) = 0;
```

The above code will cause this error. The fix is to change declaration of 2nd to:

```
virtual void value(MyStruct & struct) const = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, when i tried to change member data in a const declared method.

As we all know, const methods are supposed not to change member data.
The compiler gcc/clang doesn't return good error message.

It successfully compiled after removing const specifier from

```cpp
void I_am_a_const_method_but_trying_to_modify_member() const{
        amap.emplace(std::make_tuple(1, 1, "a"), 1);
    }
```

[compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/iXLmz3)